# Unable to post to Facebook using UI Activity View Controller

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying create a "share your score post" for my app to post on Facebook and twitter.I am using activity view controller, But I am having problems when I try to post it to Facebook(I have no problem posting to twitter with the url that I want). I searched for this issue but I couldn't find useful information that would fix my problem.

**Code:**

```
NSString *SharedContent =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"I just got %@ points in myapp.\n Think you can do better? %@ ",[formatter stringFromNumber:_LastGameResult.TotalScore],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myapp.co/Home/GetApp"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[SharedContent,[modelClass GetImage]] applicationActivities:applicationActivities];    
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For some reason Facebook doesn't accept when my url is `http://myapp.co/Home/GetApp` but I am able to post when the url is `http://myapp.co/`

**my question**

I need to able to post using `http://myapp.co/Home/GetApp` url. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have a Facebook account set on on your device (in the settings app)? It is easy to forget on a simulator :-)

Comment: Yes I have my fbdisplay name, aphid and url types

Comment: No, I do not means "Can you log on Facebook", I mean in the generals "settings" app of your device, where you can change things like the wallpaper of your phone, there is a Facebook option. You need to have filled these informations for the UIActivityViewController to work. It will not use your API Key or anything you did on the Facebook dev portal, it just need the user to have given is credential in the settings app.

Comment: Anyway, if it works with a certain kind of URL and not some others, matter is elsewhere.

Comment: Yep, it seems like the domain I want to use is somehow blocked. Any idea how to unblock?